# Libgdx tool Hiero not displaying freetype font preview

Tags: libgdx, freetype

I am using Hiero tool to generate freetype font, but when using freetype font it doesn't display anything, see below :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the background colour?

Comment: Yes, actually the font color is white. When I select Java or Native rendering, it's OK but not with freetype.

Comment: I also had the same problem with my mac. In windows there is no problem. One solution that works sometimes is resize the window. But it does not work everytime

Answer (score 1):

No reason found for such a behaviour do it in your code using FreeTypeFontGenerator

add your font.fnt file to your assest directory then
sample:

```
public static BitmapFont fontBig35 = null;
FreeTypeFontGenerator gen = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("ARLRDBD.TTF"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter pa = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
pa.size =125;
pa.color = Color.WHITE;
fontBig35 = gen.generateFont(pa);
gen.dispose();
```